# Cannot set Drag Image for draggable element in HTML5 with canvas and image

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

I am using html2canvas library to make a shadow image of dragged divs with below code

Javascript

```
function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", ev.target.id);

html2canvas(ev.target).then(function(canvas) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.body.appendChild(image);
    ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(image, 0, 0);

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragend="dragEnd(event)" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"></div>
```

I can see a Image that produced by html2canvas (added in document.body) but it's not appears during element is dragged

Thank in advance

Comment: Have you eventually managed to solve this issue?

Comment: I did try but no result.

Answer (score 0):

html2canvas is an asynchronous method, while dragging is synchronous, so it's possible to not get the correct image. I recommend calling html2canvas and setting the correct image before the drag event starts.